# Generator usage in Python

Tags: python, generator

I'm learning about generators, so I defined the following function which calculates Fibonacci sequence:

```
def fib(max):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < max:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
```

I tried to use it like this, but it didn't work:

```
next(fib(10))
Out[413]: 0

next(fib(10))
Out[414]: 0

next(fib(10))
Out[415]: 0
```

However, using it like this works as expected:

```
f = fib(10)

next(f)
Out[417]: 0

next(f)
Out[418]: 1

next(f)
Out[419]: 1

next(f)
Out[420]: 2
```

Why the first case does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next(iterator[, default])`

> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by calling its next() method. If default is given, it is returned if the iterator is exhausted, otherwise StopIteration is raised.

The first one works:

It just generates a new `iterator` for each of the functions instances you make when you call`fib(10)`

So, every time you call `fib(10)` you create a new fib function instance that returns an `iterator` specific to that instance.

Notice that they all return the first value correctly.

Comment: Oh, so calling fib(10) several times is not the same as calling f several times?

Comment: Every time you call `fib(10)` you are calling an entirely new function, but when you call `f` you are calling a single instance of `fib(10)`

Comment: Ok, that explains it.

Comment: @MichaelSB I am glad it made sense!

Answer (score 0):

when you run it in the first case it starts again from the beginning and so it'll always just go start --> first, while in the second case everytime you call f, f is changing so it goes start --> first --> second --> third.